# How to minimize bugs invoked by programmer's manual input?

Tags: language-agnostic

Sometimes all we have to work with manual input, not relying on Intellisense - with components, XML, other declarative things, strings, dynamic languages, scripts. Do you have some useful skills which minimize bugs invoked by manual input?

I don't mean coloring - it is more or less trivial and usually don't depend on programmer. But such things as don't use l or 1 in identificators or use not use autoreplace, or use particular sequence of actions to find mispelled string quickly - this i think may be useful.

Comment: Ah, I get it -- 'mispelled' is a self-referencing word.

Answer (score 2):

For editing XML, you definitely want to have a text editor that can point out sections that are not well-formed (as opposed to blind notepad editing).

An editor with good syntax coloring is also highly valuable.

Answer (score 1):

*Attention* to **detail**, aside from using your compiler of course.

Answer (score 1):

One good way to avoid human error is to **limit overtime**: exhausted people are less focused and make more errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use the compiler find these bugs.

What sort of techniques are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Don't be hasty. Think about what you're doing, and don't make typos.

To train yourself, I suggest notepad/nano(pico). Using those editors will *force* you to program correctly with only the power of your mind....not the crutch tools can become.

Answer (score 0):

Good testers, flexible schedule, vacations, good source control culture and responsible management hiring reponsible people?